# SQL Script for Backup *Error

Tags: sql, backup

First of all I don't understand much on this mater, I grab this script from some place in the net long time ago, and being using it for automated backup trough Task Scheduler in Windows, but for some reason in a recent implementation it only backups some DBases, what I noticed is that any DB name that starts with a number doesn't backup, all the other does.

Can someone look at this and give me a help, thanks in advance for any help.

This is the Script I'm using:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 

USE master
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON 


DECLARE @dayofweek varchar(20)

SELECT 
      @dayofweek = CASE datepart(dw, getdate())
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Domingo'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Segunda'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Terca'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Quarta'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Quinta'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Sexta'
         WHEN 7 THEN 'Sabado'
      END

DECLARE @OutputPath varchar(500)
DECLARE @DatabaseBackupFile varchar(500)
DECLARE @FolderName varchar(25)
DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(25)
DECLARE @strSQL varchar(2000)
DECLARE @hostname varchar(255)

SET @hostname = (select replace(convert(varchar(255),serverproperty('SERVERNAME')), '\','_'))
SET @OutputPath = 'B:\BACKUPS_SQL'

DECLARE cur_Backup CURSOR FOR 
select name from sysdatabases where name != 'master' and name != 'model' and name != 'msdb' and name != 'temdb'

OPEN cur_Backup

-- Fetch the db names from Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Backup INTO @DatabaseName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


SET @DatabaseBackupFile  = @OutputPath + '\' + @hostname + ' - ' + @DatabaseName + ' - ' +  @dayofweek + '.bak'

print @DatabaseBackupFile


SET @strSQL = 'BACKUP DATABASE '+@DatabaseName+' TO  DISK = "'+ @DatabaseBackupFile+ '" WITH  RETAINDAYS = 7, NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N''Full Database Backup'', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10'

PRINT @strSQL
EXEC (@strSQL)

 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Backup INTO @DatabaseName
END

-- Distroy Cursor 
CLOSE cur_Backup
DEALLOCATE cur_Backup


SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

And I get this error in the log file for every DBase witch start by a number:

```
B:\BACKUPS_SQL\WINRT02_SAGE - 234RH - Quarta.bak
BACKUP DATABASE 234RH TO  DISK = "B:\BACKUPS_SQL\WINRT02_SAGE - 234RH - Quarta.bak" WITH  RETAINDAYS = 7, NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server WINRT02\SAGE, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '234'.
```

Comment: I don't understand why it cuts my first line in the post above, and doesn't care of my edits, don't mean to be rude, my first line was a Hi everybody, thanks.

Comment: Try adding your database name in square bracket(i.e. [DB_Name]). This may raise error because you are using dynamic sql to create database backup.

Comment: Vad Soft you are the man, thank you so much, this was driving me crazy